# Winform with Custom DialogForm with ComboBox feeding from List<>

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class

I'm stuck, and couldn't find anything on the site to help me.

What I have:

I have a WinForms app, written in C# with Visual Studio 2010. 
I have built a custom class with about 10 data fields and properties.
On my main form, I have declared a List<> for the housing of each object. It is declared on Form Level.
I have created a custom form (since `MessageBox`/`Interaction.InputBox` won't work) for data entry with mostly textboxes and `DateTime` elements. 
Also has one `ComboBox`. Stuck at `Customdialog_Load` event handler - want to fill when form loads up.

Problem:

I need to feed the `ComboBox` with items when the form loads to enter data. It needs to feed from the `List<>` in the main form, from a specific properties, let's call it `ClientName`. If there are 50 clients listed in my `List<>`, then I want their Name Properties to populate the combobox `Collection[]`.

Request:

Can anyone please advise on how to go about feeding a `ComboBox` which is not on the same form, preferably without duplicating data/`List<>`. I can do most of the other things, and the logic flow is all correct. I do know how to add items to a collection the normal way, on the same form.

### Edit:

I can make a separate array for client names on the main form if I have to. But it HAS to be on the main form. So the combobox will still need to be populated from an array from a different form.

### Edit 2:

I'm still 1st year at University. We haven't done `DataBinding` yet, but I do know that there are better ways to do what I want to accomplish, I just don't have the tools in my mind yet. I work way ahead of the class. Thank you for all the help, very quick! Will keep on trying!

Comment: I'm sorry that your university is teaching you WinForms instead of CS.

Comment: Yah well, being in ZA, the universities really did start to bend over for the government. So, most of the degrees are suited to help the "previously disadvantaged" to get degrees. You quickly realise that they only try to teach us basics and to have the "feel good" feeling going. Any *really* good books out there that can suppliment me? I dont care for being awake ech night till 3am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the instance of your second form, pass in the constructor the reference to your List and store it in a form level variable inside the second form. Then use it to initialize your combobox in that form load event

in your main form

```
List<Customer> myCustomerList;

.....
using(Customdialog f = new CustomDialog(myCustomerList))
{
    if(DialogResult.OK == f.ShowDialog())
    {
        ..... 
    }
}
```

in your CustomDialog class

```
public class CustomDialog
{
    List<Customer> _customerList;

    public CustomDialog(List<Customer> customers)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _customerList = customers;
    }

    private void CustomDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         comboBox1.DataSource = _customerList; 
         comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";  // Supposing the Customer object contains ID property
         comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ClientName";   // The property shown on the combobox items
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this now. But will this recreate another seperate List<> on the customdialog? If my list gets large, won't this slow the program down alot each time I want to add an entry?

Comment: No, in this way you pass only a reference to your original list. A reference is only a variable that points to the same list. If you try to add a new item using the reference, only one copy of the new item exist because the original and the reference points to the same collection of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyDialog : Form
{
    public IEnumerable<Whatever> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set 
        { 
            _items = value; 
            someComboBox.Items = value; 
        }
    }

    public MyDialog(IEnumerable<Whatever> items) 
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = items;
    }
}
```

Now you can pass them in via the constructor and/or separately at a later time.

Comment: This will actually generate an exception, if I recall correctly.  You'd have to set the list of items only after the form has been instantiated, not in the constructor.

Comment: Been ages since winforms but doesn't each control have an InitialiseComponent() call? Surely it's safe to put it after this call since the forms child controls will have been instantiated.

Comment: @TedSpence: You can set the items in the constructor, not sure why you think one cannot.

Comment: @Charleh: Yes, there will be a call to `InitializeComponent`. As this was just a trivial example I left out boilerplate code, but I can add it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced down the Winforms route then :( but it sounds like you need some advice on passing stuff around (and maybe databinding?)

Ideally you need to get the data across to the custom form (I assume you have a main form and a popup/another form that opens).

One way to do it is to create a property on the second form which is of the `List<>` type and assign it before you open the form... e.g.

in form2.cs

```
// an auto property will work well here
public List<YourClass> YourClassList { get; set;}
```

Then in your form1.cs

```
// When the user opens the second form
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.YourClassList = yourClassListFromThisForm;
frm2.ShowDialog(); // etc
```

Are you also having a problem filling the box or using databinding?

To be honest, if you haven't done much work on this, I'd seriously consider moving to WPF - it's just so much better in every respect

Comment: *"I'd seriously consider moving to WPF - it's just so much better in every respect"* - Highly debatable.  It's far *worse* in many respects, specifically the way it makes tasks that are easy in WinForms incredibly difficult and convoluted.

Comment: The idea of making the List<> public sounds good. Thanks. Will move to WPF later. Read edit2 on main post :]

Comment: @Ed S. can you quantify that with some examples? I always found WPF a much more natural fit for me - and the amount of control you have over look and feel is something that's very important as far as I'm concerned. I also love the databinding - binding things to other things is built-in and is very powerful. I've found things much quicker and easier to develop using WPF - things that I couldn't do in winforms or would require the use of 3rd party controls

Comment: I'm 100% with you on the control WPF gives you in regards to look and feel, it's excellent.  I'm not a fan of the fact that handling mouse events is so much more complicated.  I don't particularly like the massive amount of boilerplate code that binding sometimes requires (i.e., creating all sorts of new types and converters to do seemingly simple things).  I don't like when you run into a situation which doesn't fit well with the data binding approach.  When you have to drop into code to do things it become far more complex than it ever was in WinForms.

Comment: Graphical features which used to be difficult in WinForms all of a sudden became almost trivial.  Many of the more mundane tasks which were simple in WinForms became much harder as a result.

Comment: Don't really get what you mean by dropping into code to do things is harder - since you are leveraging the same framework. The mouse events thing is also questionable since you can either use events or use command bindings so you have more flexibility - are you talking about routed events in the logical tree? I agree with converters being a pain, but they work and they provide a way to wire a highly decoupled UI to your business layer. Since I write biz apps, I can't think of a scenario where I wouldn't use databinding! I suppose it's subjective - it just fits me like a glove...forms never did

Comment: It's not the same framework, not sure what you mean by that.  Mouse events are quite a bit more complicated due to the logical tree and how other controls eat them up before they arrive.  Great for making complex controls, not so great for tasks that should be simple.  Flexibility comes at a cost (complexity).  I'm not a UI guy, I'm a systems programmer.  I don't like writing UI's.  However, I was brought in to work on the interface to our machine due to a lack of resources.  I knew WinForms, I learned WPF.  It was great for some things, others just became complicated...

Comment: Patterns like MVVM make your life harder when you need to step outside of their intended use a bit (and those situations occur in any non-trivial application).  I don't hate WPF, I just wouldn't espouse it as "so much better in *every* respect".  It certainly is not, and for a simple UI I would still take WinForms over WPF any day.